# Inserting data into MySQL 5.5 using PHP 5.3

Tags: php

I am having problem inserting data from a form into MySQL 5.5 database using PHP 5.3
I am able to insert my data, however I get duplicate insertions.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$host ="localhost";
$user ="root";
$password ="password";
$database ="database1";
$table ="users";

mysql_connect("$host","$user","$password")or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("$database")or die(mysql_error());
$mysql = "INSERT INTO $table (username,password)
          VALUES('$_POST[username]','$_POST[password]')";
if(!mysql_query($mysql)) die(mysql_error());
echo"Data inserted";
mysql_close();
?>
```

The error message I get is

```
"undefined index:username" 
"undefined index:password"
```

My table fields are three id, username and password.

Comment: Stop using `mysql_` and switch over to [`mysqli`](http://us.php.net/mysqli) or [`PDO`](http://us.php.net/pdo). Of course that won't stop the "undefined index" errors, it's just a general recommendation. The errors happen because you're not POSTing those fields to the server... can't be answered properly without seeing the HTML code for the form that submits to this page.

Comment: If you are getting duplicate insertions, your code is probably being _called twice_. Common reasons for this are faulty webserver rewrite rules (check your web logs for duplicate requests) or empty `src=` attributes in `<img>, <script>` tags or `<link rel=>`  Start with your web server logs. Do you see two lines per request?

Comment: Check the field has name="id" name="username" name="password". Did you check the values are passing correctly

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski: also, not using Post-Redirect-Get means refreshing the page inserts again.

Comment: Are you getting duplicate insertions or the error "undefined index:username"? As for the error, check the fields in your form,

Answer (score 0):

You are getting `notice` error.

Check whether `$_POST['username']` exist or not

```
if(isset($_POST[username]) && isset($_POST[password])){
       $host ="localhost";
       $user ="root";
       $password ="password";
       $database ="database1";
       $table ="users";
       mysql_connect("$host","$user","$password")or die(mysql_error());
       mysql_select_db("$database")or die(mysql_error());
       $mysql = "INSERT INTO $table (username,password)
       VALUES('$_POST[username]','$_POST[password]')";
       if(!mysql_query($mysql)) die(mysql_error());
       echo"Data inserted";
       mysql_close();
}
```

You are getting duplicate insertion because you are not checking whether username is already exist in database or not. Before doing `INSERT` check whether the username already exist in database, if already exist then don't allow insert.

Use mysqli or pdo for connecting database. mysql_* function will be deprecated soon.

Answer (score 0):

Rememeber to escape the data using `mysqli_real_escape_string` or `mysql_real_escape_string` before you insert it into the database.

As other have said, use `mysqli_*` instead of `mysql_*`

Answer (score 0):

I remember 5.5 it was a little stressful...try this

```
$user=_$POST['username'];
$pass=_$POST['password'];

$sql="INSERT INTO $table (username, password) VALUES ('$user', '$pass')";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result) 
{
echo "Entered data successfully";
}
else
{
echo "data not posted";
}
mysql_close($conn);
?>
```

but with 5.5 the main thing I was the lack of ' around username and password in your _POST statements...it weird the console don't need it, but most the browsers do.....

Comment: Keep in mind that this code is extremely vulnerable to SQL injection. Also you've got a type-o in lines 1 and 2.